# How to specialize a template function for integral and floating types respectively?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider function `template<typename T> void Fun(T t);`.
How can I have different implementations of it for integral and floating types respectively?

I guess building blocks are `std::enable_if`, `std::is_integral`, `std::is_floating_point`. But I cannot put them together in an elegant way :-( .

P.S. I got C++11 available.

Comment: Instead of `enable_if`/SFINAE, you can also use [tag dispatch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6917079/420683). Tag dispatch is often simpler and more straight-forward, but can require slightly more code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the example code for [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com).

**EDIT:**

Adapted the code from the link above as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>


template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type foo(T t) 
{
    std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type foo(T t) 
{
    std::cout << "is real" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(1); 
    foo(1.0);
}
```

The definition of `enable_if` is `template< bool B, class T = void > struct enable_if;`. This gives the following options for return value type:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type foo(T t) // void return type

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type foo(T t) // return type from template parameter

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, size_t>::type foo(T t) // fixed return type
```

Comment: I asked this question after came back from there. Just edited my question. My function have fix return type. So the tricks at cppreference.com do not apply.

Comment: @updogliu `enable_if` actually has two template parameters, the second one is defaulted to `void`. When the condition (the first template parameter) is `true`, `std::enable_if<..>::type` yields the *second* template parameter (here: `void`). If that's still a problem, you can use `enable_if` on a defaulted additional template parameter of `foo`, e.g. `template<class T, class = typename std::enable_if<..>::type> void foo(T);`

Comment: In C++14 the return type can be slightly simplified to `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>` (i.e. no preceding `typename` and no `::type` at the end - for the cost of adding a strategic "_t").