# sort container of pointers c++ and compare type

Tags: c++, sorting, containers

i need sort container. 
but i get the type of container from template.. 
beacouse this i need to use `std::sort` for `std::vector` and `name.sort` for `std::list`.
and therefore i need check the type of container in order to chose what to do.

i try to do:

```
class sor {
public:
    sor(){}
    bool operator( )(Course* l, Course* r) {
        return l->getNumber() < r->getNumber();
    }
};



if (typeid(courses) == std::list){
    //do something...
}
else{
   //do...
}
```

how can i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could overload your own sort function

```
template<typename T, typename Compare>
void sort(std::list<T>& list, Compare compare)
{
    list.sort(compare);
}

template<typename T, typename Compare>
void sort(std::vector<T>& vector, Compare compare)
{
    std::sort(vector.begin(),vector.end(),compare);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm is somehow container independent (it requires iterator to meet the requirements of [`ValueSwappable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable) and [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)) so you can use it like:

```
std::sort(container.begin(), container.end(), sor());
```

Unfortunately [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) does not satisfy [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), though.

---

If you have a template function that accepts any container type, you can provide specializations to it. Alternatively, with [*type traits*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) you can provide more general template "overloads":

```
template<class... Args, template<class...> class Container>
void sort(Container<Args...>&) { ... }

template<class... Args>
void sort(std::list<Args...>&) { ... }
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04a9a393e498d89e)

Comment: So how can I to compare between the types?

Comment: @user3630497, why do you need to compare the types? Also, where's the template function?

Comment: i need to compare the type becouse i wnat to use std::sort for std::vector. and use sort of list for std::list

Comment: i cant compare between tham?

Comment: there's a [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) with the usual `O(NlogN)` complexity.  As far as I know it has no (significant) extra memory usage.  So I'm not sure what your comment is about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [type traits](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-type-traits/184404270) and [tag dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917079/tag-dispatch-versus-static-methods-on-partially-specialised-classes) see code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct vectorlike_tag { };
struct listlike_tag   { };

template <typename C> struct container_traits;

template <typename T, typename A>
struct container_traits<std::vector<T, A>> {
  typedef vectorlike_tag category;
};

template <typename T, typename A>
struct container_traits<std::list<T, A>> {
  typedef listlike_tag category;
};

template <typename Container, typename Compare>
void sort_helper(Container& c, Compare f, vectorlike_tag) {
  std::sort(c.begin(), c.end(), f);
}

template <typename Container, typename Compare>
void sort_helper(Container& c, Compare f, listlike_tag) {
  c.sort(f);
}

template <typename Container, typename Compare>
void sort_container(Container &c, Compare f) {
  sort_helper(c, f, typename container_traits<Container>::category());
}

template<class Container>
void sort_container(Container &c)
{
  sort_helper(c, std::less<typename Container::value_type>(), typename container_traits<Container>::category());
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{ 4, 3, 7, 8, 9 };
  sort_container(v);
  for (auto e : v) std::cout << e << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::list<int> lst{ 4, 3, 7, 8, 9 };
  sort_container(lst, std::greater<int>());
  for (auto e : lst) std::cout << e << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

### Output:

> 3 4 7 8 9
>
> 9 8 7 4 3